# How to define an optional setting value in the datepicker using Material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, datepicker

I am trying to create a reusable component of the Material datepicker but I can't find a solution to have a optional setting date of the component.

**resusable.datepicker.component.ts**

```
@Input() currentValue: FormControl = new FormControl<any>(new Date());
```

**resusable.datepicker.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <input
    name="{{ name }}"
    matInput
    [matDatepicker]="picker"
    [value]="currentValue.value"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**usage.component.html**

```
<app-ftd-date-picker
  [currentValue]="selectedDate"
></app-ftd-date-picker>
<app-ftd-date-picker
></app-ftd-date-picker>
```

**usage.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedDate = new FormControl(new Date(2025, 11, 25));
}
```

The problem is that when i use the component without setting the default date, it needs to have this changed:
**resusable.datepicker.component.ts**

```
@Input() currentValue: FormControl = new FormControl<any> | undefined;
```

But i am unable to find a solution. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Can your input just be the date object itself instead of the FormControl?  That way, you can take the input if provided, otherwise initialize the value to the date you want as the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was clear after a night sleep... just change this line:

**resusable.datepicker.component.ts**

```
@Input() currentValue: FormControl = new FormControl();
```

This way the typing is correct and the default is a *non* date.